# How to add label to a point in scatterplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to label the points on my scatter plot in tikz. Like for the blue square point, I want to add a lable next to it on the plot itself. Something like a label saying '3x5' next to the blue sqaures, while '3x10' next ti the red squares. Is there a way I can do that with my code. Thanks

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{
  set layers,% using layers
  mark layer=axis tick labels% defines the layer of the marks
}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1e7,
ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e3,
xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
scatter/classes={ a={mark=square*, blue}, b={mark=square*, red}, c={mark=square, black}, d={mark=triangle*, blue}, e={mark=triangle*, red},f={mark=triangle*, black},g={mark=x, black}, h={mark= diamond*, pink} },
] 
\addplot[scatter, only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic]
table[meta=label] {
x     y      label
320 0.608216725 a
500 0.522425565 b
1100    0.362002313 c
3260    0.03403538 a 
11420   0.002463198 b
43100   0.000725737 c


};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet complete so that it is compilable as is. Also, `xmin=0` does not really make sense with a `loglogaxis`. To add labels to the nodes, you can maybe add `nodes near coords*` to the options for `\addplot`.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Doing that.

Comment: @JasperHabicht can you now look at the code, I have updated it. It will work now.

Comment: Do you want different labels for every single node? Do you want to add the same label to all the blue nodes (and another to all the red nodes)? Do you want to add one label to one single blue node? Depending on what you want, the solution might differ.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a label to every node, it would be best to add to your table another column that contains the values for these labels. You can then access these values using a combination of the `visualization depends on` and `nodes near coords*` options as shown in the following example.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
    %xmin=0, 
    xmax=1e7,
    ymin=1e-4, 
    ymax=1e3,
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*, blue}, 
        b={mark=square*, red}, 
        c={mark=square, black}, 
        d={mark=triangle*, blue}, 
        e={mark=triangle*, red},
        f={mark=triangle*, black},
        g={mark=x, black}, 
        h={mark= diamond*, pink}
    },
] 

\addplot[
        scatter, 
        only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords*={\annotvalue},
        node near coord style={rotate=45, anchor=south west, font=\scriptsize},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{annotation} \as \annotvalue},
    ]
    table[meta=label] {
        x       y            label  annotation
        320     0.608216725  a      $3\times5$
        500     0.522425565  b      $3\times10$
        1100    0.362002313  c      $3\times10$
        3260    0.03403538   a      $3\times5$
        11420   0.002463198  b      $3\times10$
        43100   0.000725737  c      $3\times5$
    };

\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that using `visualization depends on`, the relevant macro will only be updated if the corresponding values in the table exists. So, if you want to omit a label, you would need to add `\null` to your table for the relevant entry.

---

Another way would be to add a legend:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{loglogaxis}[
    %xmin=0, 
    xmax=1e7,
    ymin=1e-4, 
    ymax=1e3,
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*, blue}, 
        b={mark=square*, red}, 
        c={mark=square, black}, 
        d={mark=triangle*, blue}, 
        e={mark=triangle*, red},
        f={mark=triangle*, black},
        g={mark=x, black}, 
        h={mark= diamond*, pink}
    },
] 

\addplot[
        scatter, 
        only marks,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic
    ]
    table[meta=label] {
        x       y            label
        320     0.608216725  a
        500     0.522425565  b
        1100    0.362002313  c
        3260    0.03403538   a
        11420   0.002463198  b
        43100   0.000725737  c
    };

\legend{$3\times5$, $3\times10$, $3\times15$}

\end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]