# Pgfplots: How to add values of macros from a loop on the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to add the values of \wA and \wB at each point in the graph. I tried many ways at they do not work. Please help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Standard Deviation},
            ylabel={Expected Return},
            xmin=0.03,
            xmax=0.065,
            ymin=0.05,
            ymax=0.08,
            xtick={0,.01,...,1},
            ytick={0,.01,...,1},
            width=\textwidth,    height=8cm,
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},    scaled ticks=false,
            yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},    scaled ticks=false,
            ]
            
            % Stock A: expected return = 0.06, standard deviation = 0.04
            \def\sigmaA{0.04}
            \def\muA{0.06}
            
            % Stock B: expected return = 0.08, standard deviation = 0.06
            \def\sigmaB{0.06}
            \def\muB{0.08}
            
            % Form 10 different portfolios with different weights of stocks A and B
                \foreach \i in {0,20,40,...,100}
             {
                % Calculate the weights of stocks A and B
                \pgfmathsetmacro\wA{\fpeval{(\i/100)}}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\wB}{1-\wA}
                % Calculate expected return of portfolio
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\muP}{\wA*\muA + \wB*\muB}
                % Calculate standard deviation of portfolio
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\sigmaP}{sqrt(\wA*\wA*\sigmaA*\sigmaA + \wB*\wB*\sigmaB*\sigmaB + 2*\wA*\wB*0.4*\sigmaA*\sigmaB)}
                % Plot portfolio
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {(\sigmaP,\muP)} ;
             }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `nodes near coords` to the `axis` options. Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675934/47927

Comment: Sorry, I probably closed this too quickly, but you can really add some combination of `nodes near coords` and `visualization depends on` options to the axis environment such as: `nodes near coords={wA: $\wAvalue$, wB: $\wBvalue$}, visualization depends on={value \fpeval{(\i/100)} \as \wAvalue}, visualization depends on={value \fpeval{1-(\i/100)} \as \wBvalue}`

Comment: Thanks. That works